# WLOG and "by symmetry" arguments and the foundations of mathematics

Tags: logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation

John Harrison's paper [Without Loss of Generality](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jrh13/papers/wlog.pdf) raises the interesting point that although "without loss of generality"/"by symmetry" arguments are a common proof technique, there is no corresponding formal mathematical law, so that automated theorem provers must be extended to handle such arguments.

If ATPs cannot handle WLOG arguments in formal logic, can humans? Is it impossible to prove the WLOG argument in the general case in any of the conventional foundational logics of mathematics? If so, then does this indicate a deficit or shortfall or is the WLOG argument A) too trivial, or B) too metalogical?

I will clarify what I mean by a WLOG argument. In mathematical logic, if a pair of objects $A$ and $B$ are known to be indistinguishable up to naming, it is immediate that a proof of any property $P$ of $A$ automatically implies $P(B)$ and, conversely, $P(B) \to P(A)$. Such "Without loss of generality" or "by symmetry" arguments are used almost everywhere in mathematics and to say that the reasoning is obvious would be an enormous understatement.

(To be precise, I want to emphasize that WLOG doesn't apply when some property of the objects is unknown and, when discovered, assigned to each of the objects arbitrarily. For example, although the roots of a polynomial are indistinguishable in the sense that the coefficients are invariant over permutation of the roots, it may be possible to discover the set of values and then make an arbitrary assignment of values to names. Indistinguishability is not the same as uncertainty.)

It could be argued that WLOG arguments are, like the cut rule, superfluous since they are only used to avoid needless repetition. However, since one may be referring to an uncountable or larger set of objects the WLOG argument may be necessary for the existence of a proof of finite length.

Perhaps what is needed is some kind of an axiom to patch this hole up?

Comment: "If ATPs cannot handle WLOG arguments in formal logic, can humans?" Well, we handle them every day. =)

Comment: Sorry. I was arguing that humans can't prove WLOG *formally* from foundational theories such as ZFC. Everyday mathematical reasoning is  informal, but most informal proofs can be formalized if someone has the time and effort. I just don't see how WLOG can follow from any of the axioms of, say, ZFC. But I am not a set theorist, so I am probably missing something obvious here.

And I also want to make clear that I am talking about proving the general case of WLOG, not just for one specific instance.

Answer (score 7):

The paper does not claim that automated theorem provers cannot handle the case of such arguments, and indeed shows how to formalize them. The fact is that humans do not write proofs in the same way that ATPs do - very much is left for the reader to do. Indeed, this often rises to the level of little lemmas that could have their own proofs, and the author may only hint at how one might prove them.

This is exactly the case when we say "without loss of generality" - we are alluding to an omitted proof. The lemma would generally be of the form:

> There is some group of symmetries preserving the properties at hand in the problem. There exists a symmetry such that _____ properties hold.

And this is more or less what the theorems that linked paper proves amount to. The proof should be obvious to the reader, but not to a machine.

So, on one hand, we cannot patch this hole, because there is no overarching proof of *every* such lemma we might want. But, on the other hand, there really is no hole to begin with - it's just another thing we need to translate for the machine.

Comment: You are quite right, I expressed myself very poorly and I'm asking for the question to be deleted as a result. Thanks for the answer however!

I still don't understand how one is supposed to express that symmetries exist within the sentences of a formal theory itself - this is a self-referential statement that the axioms of mathematics just don't allow. Notice how Harrison states in his version of the proof of the case of WLOG "But the theorem is completely symmetric between a,b and c," - the proof of the theorem is talking about the sentences of the theorem itself being symmetric.

Comment: The way the paper formalizes it is to directly require the symmetry - i.e. it requires $P(x,y)\Leftrightarrow P(y,x)$. This could require its own proof, but it no different from the part of induction requiring $P(n)\Rightarrow P(n+1)$. In general, one may easily show various $P$ to be propositions over some structure - e.g. "unordered pairs of reals" or "vector spaces with an ordered pair of identified points"or whatever - and that, when we are so precise about what structure we have, we may too be precise about what isomorphisms we can apply

Comment: Yes, you can assume such symmetry properties by fiat but I am talking about proving the general or universal WLOG argument from foundational theories rather than requiring that WLOG holds as a precondition. I am interested in the question - how do you formally deduce the general WLOG argument from foundational axioms such as mathematical induction? All I am suggesting is that the argument is so obvious and trivial that its independence from the axioms of set theory may have been overlooked. Btw I sincerely apologize for mischaracterizing Harrison's paper and thanks for correcting me so nicely.

Comment: @calculemur What do you mean "the general WLOG argument"? The most general case you could possibly write is "If $P(f(x)) \rightarrow P(x)$ and $P(f(x))$, then $P(x)$." The truth of that is trivial. My point in the post is that when we write "without loss of generality", we are generally indicating that we are presenting a proof of $P(f(x))$ and leaving the proof of $P(f(x))\rightarrow P(x)$ to the reader.